# Background and other css features not showing in Django

Tags: css, django

**base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DPU</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}"/>
    <style>
    h1 {color:red;}
    p {color:blue;}
    </style>
</head>

<hr>
<h1>Disease Polling Unit</h1>
<hr>
{% block main_content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The background,fonts are not showing after including it as staticfiles in base.html.What could I be doing wrong?

**polls/static/polls/style.css**

```
li a {
    color:red;
    font-size:20px;
}

body {
    background:white url('images:pil1.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: The first thing you have to check is if the css file is loaded.

Comment: Like @guillermochamorro mentioned, check if the css files have loaded. View page source option and click on the link to css file in the **href** attribute. If it is not loaded, then there is some issue with the static file configuration. Need to see your static file configuration in settings.py